# How to ssh into HA application gears?

Tags: openshift, openshift-gears

As was explained in the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11730590/what-are-some-of-the-tricks-to-using-openshift it should be possible to ssh into some of the other gears when using a scaled app with openshift.

Unfortunately the link mentioned there (https://openshift.redhat.com/community/faq/can-i-access-my-applications-gear) seems to be gone.

Via [my app url]/haproxy-status/ I can see the names of the other gears. They are long names like gear-[long number]-[app name]. Using that name I can no longer ssh into them when I'm ssh'ed into the main gear. ssh there just immediately returns without any error.

If I do `ssh blala` the same thing happened, so it looks like ssh had been replaced by a noop command on the primary gear?

When I examine the haproxy conf file, I see entries like;

```
server gear-[long number]-[app name] ex-std-node[number].prod.rhcloud.com:[number] check fall 2 ...
```

I tried ssh'ing into this `ext-std-node...` address as well, both from the main/primary application gear as well as from my desktop, but it didn't work in both cases.

How can I get shell access to my other gears?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This command shows how to access individual gears:

```
rhc app show <appname> --gears
```

The last column of output is the ssh URL.  It is of the form $UUID@$UUID-$NAMESPACE.rhcloud.com .  You can ssh into them directly, and they are also accessible via ssh from the "head" gear; they have to be, since git pushes are synchronized from the head gear to the others via ssh.

Comment: Is there any way to do it inside a gear?

Comment: It is possible to query the openshift broker from inside a gear, but I do not think there is a CLI.  You can make a call to https://<broker_host>/broker/rest/domains/$OPENSHIFT_NAMESPACE/applications/$OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME/gear_groups.json (using the auth token in ~/.auth/) and parse the result.  Using existing modules, this works: `oo-ruby -r openshift-origin-node/model/application_container -e "::OpenShift::Runtime::ApplicationContainer.from_uuid(ENV['OPENSHIFT_GEAR_UUID']).get_gear_groups(ENV)['data'].each { |gg| gg['gears'].each { |g| puts g['ssh_url'] } }"`